Seleccionar campos a mostrar desde una consulta mysql usando php
tengo la siguiente situación: Necesito realizar un script de una consulta mysql,usando php y html, donde el usuario pueda seleccionar los campos a mostrar de dicha consulta.
Hasta los momentos he realizado lo siguiente:
Archivo "reporte.php" que permite seleccionar los campos de la tabla mysql.
<form action="generar_reporte.php" method="post">
<label for="campos">Selecciona los campos:</label>
<select name="campos[]" multiple>
    <option value="cedula">Cédula</option>
    <option value="nombre">Nombre</option>
    <option value="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</option>
    <option value="direccion">Dirección</option>
    <option value="departamento">Departamento</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Generar Reporte">

Archivo "generar_reporte.php" que realiza la conexion y procesa la consulta.
<?php
 include 'conexion.php'; // Incluye el archivo de conexión

 $campos_seleccionados = $_POST['campos']; // Campos seleccionados por el usuario

// Construye la consulta SQL
$sql = 'SELECT ' . implode(', ', $campos_seleccionados) . ' FROM personas';

// Ejecuta la consulta y muestra los resultados

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  // esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora sin resultados esperados, ya que muestra todos los campos definidos.
   
 // ... 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['cedula'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['fecha_nacimiento'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['direccion'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['departamento'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>
Es en este ultimo archivo donde tengo las dudas para poder mostrar los campos seleccionados en un formato html.
Espero haberme explicado correctamente y poder contar con su ayuda. saludos

Primero que nada, te recomiendo revisar ¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?. Segundo, me parece que sería muchísimo más seguro y a prueba de errores que la consulta devuelva todos los datos y vos solo trabajes con los seleccionados, o en su defecto asegurarse que los campos son campos existentes en la tabla. Tercero, ¿podrías agregar el código que has intentado o agregar un ejmplo de cuál sería el resultado que te gustaría obtener? Porque sería tan simple como hacer un foreach sobre $campos_seleccionados

Hola Marcos, gracias por tu recomendacion para evitar la inyeccion sql en php. No he podido avanzar mas en la solucion, porque precisamente mi duda recae en como mostrar los datos usando solo los campos seleccionados por el usuario. Me gustaria que hiciera un ciclo, mostrando todos los datos pero solo de los campos seleccionados, usando php y html. espero haberme explicado bien.

No te lo tomes mal, pero es importante que compartas lo que sea que hayas intentado. Así como esta, parece que nos estas pidiendo que resolvamos tu tarea/trabajo.

No tomo nada a mal, ni espero que me resuelvan mi tarea/trabajo, solo busco ayuda en una duda que tengo y para eso se supone que es este foro. De igual manera, gracias por tu atención.

"Es en este ultimo archivo donde tengo las dudas..." Cuáles son esas dudas exactamente? Qué has hecho para resolver esas dudas?

@HGarcia mis comentarios anteriores fueron en base a que antes de que edites tu pregunta, en el código decía: "Aquí debes adaptar el código para mostrar los datos en el formato deseado". Eso sonaba a algo que primero tenias que resolver vos

@Marcos precisamente ese comentario me lo puse a mi mismo porque la solución que estaba colocando no satisfacía mi requerimiento y debía adaptar el código para que efectivamente mostrara los campos que había seleccionado.

Para imprimir de cada persona solo los campos seleccionados, podes hacerlo así:
// ... código anterior

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($campos_seleccionados as $campo) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[$campo] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}


En el caso que por cada persona ya tengas exactamente los datos seleccionados, entonces podes hacerlo así:
// ... código anterior

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}


Gracias por la respuesta, creo que es lo que estaba necesitando. Aun no he podido probarlo porque la consulta me esta generando un error. Debo corregir como concatenar el "SELECT" con el arreglo de $campos_seleccionados.
